# How to display the form's content

Tags: php, laravel

Problem with displaying content entered in the form in laravel.
What code to add to display the value entered in the form?

--web.php

```
 Route::get('/show-name', ['uses' => 'NameController@show-name', 'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

--
NameContoller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NameController extends Controller
{
    public function show-name()
    {   
        return view('show-name');
    }
}
```

--
show-name.blade.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="">
    <div class="required field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="name">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="ui primary button" id="send" name="send" value="Send"></input>
</form>
```

Message after using the button - MethodNotAllowedHttpException.
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: `Route::get` and `method="post"`

Comment: I mean, literally just reading the documentation page on this tells you everything in an easy digestible format. You want 'help' but you're unwilling to help yourself? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests seems more like you just want people to do it for you

Comment: the same message after change

Comment: They are pointing out the fact you're sending it as POST yet you're registering a GET request route.

Comment: and what did you change?

Comment: I have read the documentation, but I can not understand some of the issues, which is why I count on forum assistance. I changed here Route::post('/show-name', ['uses' => 'NameController@show-name', 'middleware' => 'auth']);

Comment: and what's in `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ?

Comment: used to make the returned value displayed on the same page

Comment: and what's in there in this situation? is it really show-name or something other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a `POST` request, not a `GET` request.

```
Route::post('/show-name', [
  'uses' => 'NameController@show-name', 
  'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

The documentation tells you how to get all the data
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input

The documentation tells you have to pass data to a view https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NameController extends Controller
{
    public function show-name(Request $request)
    {   
        $input = $request->all();
        return view('show-name')->with('data', $input);
    }
}
```

The documentation tells you how to access data passed into a view https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data

```
@php
echo print_r($data);
@endphp

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="">
    <div class="required field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="name">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="ui primary button" id="send" name="send" value="Send"></input>
</form>
```

Further more, the form won't work without `CSFR` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#forms

Inputs are self closing, meaning there is no need for `</input>`

Further more, there is no need for `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` because with Laravel, you can specifically define the name of the route.

`<form method="post" action="/show-name" class="">`

Watch some basic tutorials on Laravel because you're going about this all incorrectly.